# How to fit negative data with linear regression?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I want to  fit my data and extract their slopes. I use the linear regression. My data is a set of clock offset values that contain negative values. This is my code:

```
from scipy import stats
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
x= [1549808191, 1549808192, 1549808196, 1549808201, 1549808202, 1549808206, 1549808207, 1549808214, 1549808215, 1549808221, 1549808226, 1549808267, 1549808272, 1549808290, 1549808304, 1549808315, 1549808324, 1549808332, 1549808355, 1549808395, 1549808396]
y= ['7', '0', '0', '0', '-2', '4', '-3', '2', '0', '-1', '0', '-2', '-1', '-1','2', '-2', '1', '0', '0', '-1', '-2']
print(x)
print(y)
plt.plot(x,y,'o-')
plt.show()
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x, y)
print(slope)
```

[image]
However, it gives me this error:

```
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

So how to resolve this error please ? Is the linear regression the best way to extract fitting params with such data?

Comment: Is `y` supposed to be a list of _strings_?

Comment: @ForceBru No, my code works I can  plot the first figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemingly comes from `scipy.stats.linregress(x, y)` where you perform the fit because your `y` values are strings. You can convert them to integer type using `map` and things work as expected

```
# import commands here 
plt.style.use('ggplot')
x= [1549808191, 1549808192, 1549808196, 1549808201, 1549808202, 1549808206, 1549808207, 1549808214, 1549808215, 1549808221, 1549808226, 1549808267, 1549808272, 1549808290, 1549808304, 1549808315, 1549808324, 1549808332, 1549808355, 1549808395, 1549808396]
y= ['7', '0', '0', '0', '-2', '4', '-3', '2', '0', '-1', '0', '-2', '-1', '-1','2', '-2', '1', '0', '0', '-1', '-2']

plt.plot(x,y,'o-')
plt.show()
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x, list(map(int, y)))
print("The slope is %s" %slope)

# The slope is -0.009607415773244879
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Problem & Solution**

---

As is said in others answers, the problem is that Y values are strings. It works for you partly, because **matplotlib** automaticly change your Y-strings into numbers. However **scipy** library doesnt. Therefore you need to transform your list into numbers. See below

```
from scipy import stats
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
x= [1549808191, 1549808192, 1549808196, 1549808201, 1549808202, 1549808206, 1549808207, 1549808214, 1549808215, 1549808221, 1549808226, 1549808267, 1549808272, 1549808290, 1549808304, 1549808315, 1549808324, 1549808332, 1549808355, 1549808395, 1549808396]
y= ['7', '0', '0', '0', '-2', '4', '-3', '2', '0', '-1', '0', '-2', '-1', '-1','2', '-2', '1', '0', '0', '-1', '-2']
y = [float(i) for i in y]
print(x)
print(y)
plt.plot(x,y,'o-')
plt.show()
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x, y)
print(slope)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your y is a list of strings. You need your y to be of type integer or float to do a regression.

Comment: The code works. It gives me the first figure the problem is computing the regression parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Change y to a list of numbers: `y = [7, 0, 0, 0, -2, ...]`

This way it works

```
from scipy import stats
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
x= [1549808191, 1549808192, 1549808196, 1549808201, 1549808202, 1549808206, 1549808207, 1549808214, 1549808215, 1549808221, 1549808226, 1549808267, 1549808272, 1549808290, 1549808304, 1549808315, 1549808324, 1549808332, 1549808355, 1549808395, 1549808396]
y= [1549808191, 1549808192, 1549808196, 1549808201, 1549808202, 1549808206, 1549808207, 1549808214, 1549808215, 1549808221, 1549808226, 1549808267, 1549808272, 1549808290, 1549808304, 1549808315, 1549808324, 1549808332, 1549808355, 1549808395, 1549808396]
print(y)
plt.plot(x,y,'o-')
plt.show()
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x, y)
print(slope)
```

Returns **1**

Comment: The code works. It gives me the first figure the problem is computing the regression parameters.

Comment: no it does not work, it gives you errors. And thats because you are doing a regression on characters instead of numbers.

Comment: I just run your code with `y= [1549808191, 1549808192, 1549808196, 1549808201, 1549808202, 1549808206, 1549808207, 1549808214, 1549808215, 1549808221, 1549808226, 1549808267, 1549808272, 1549808290, 1549808304, 1549808315, 1549808324, 1549808332, 1549808355, 1549808395, 1549808396]` and now it works